# Nokogiri in Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

When I `require 'nokogiri'` in Ruby 2.0, it has a error

```
`require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/2.0/nokogiri (LoadError)
```

Is nokogiri not supporting Ruby 2.0 yet? I can see nokogiri in `gem list`

Comment: How did you install Ruby v2.0? Did you reinstall Nokogiri after installing Ruby 2.0?

Comment: I use Ruby Installer, and I have reinstalled Nokogiri =(
If I rollback to Ruby 1.9, it work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokogiri now support Ruby 2.0, even on Windows, see [HERE](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/864)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 2.0 support is not yet available for Windows. Follow along [here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/851) for updates:

Comment: It is now (even for 64 bits). See [here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/864)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works fine:

```
RUBY_VERSION # => "2.0.0"
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body><p>foo</p></body></html>')
doc.at('p').text # => "foo"
```

Comment: How do you install Nokogiri? I have tried reinstalled Nokogiri 1.5.6, but doesn't work