# Nokogiri (1.6.2) Load Error, ruby 2.0, rails 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

This is driving me crazy...

I've seen a couple questions here with nokogiri (one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332416/nokogiri-in-ruby-2-0)) but they pertain to scripts. I have a full on rails app, and I just installed paperclip, and amazon-aws which also downloaded nokogiri when I did bundle install..

```
gem dependency paperclip
...
nokogiri (>= 0, development)
...
```

So that's where this gem was introduced..

I read that Nokogiri should be in my gemfile so I did a

gemfile.rb =>

```
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'paperclip'
```

Now my local server won't start...

```
nokogiri-1.6.2.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
```

I also tried it with nokogiri 1.4.4...

Previously (without nokogiri in my gemfile) the server would load, but I would get a load error when I tried to upload an image... same error as above

```
cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri
```

There is nothing in the thotbot/paperclip docs about nokogiri.
I've tried

```
gem install nokogiri
```

and

```
gem pristine nokogiri
```

No dice..

I notice this message on bundle:

```
        IMPORTANT!  Nokogiri builds and uses a packaged version of libxml2.

        If this is a concern for you and you want to use the system library
        instead, abort this installation process and reinstall nokogiri as
        follows:

            gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries

        If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

            bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
            bundle install

        However, note that nokogiri does not necessarily support all versions
        of libxml2.

        For example, libxml2-2.9.0 and higher are currently known to be broken
        and thus unsupported by nokogiri, due to compatibility problems and
        XPath optimization bugs.
```

So I did just that

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

And I get the same errors.  So I'm at wits end. 
Any suggestions?

**** Edit:****

I think it's interaction with the AWS-SDK gem, not sure.  They dropped support for older versions in November '13, but I'm using

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.0'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5.0'
```

*sigh* I've tried Nokogiri.org install method too...

```
brew install libxml2 libxslt
brew link libxml2 libxslt

wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz
cd libiconv-1.13.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1
make
sudo make install

gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2
```

Still have the issue.  Nokogiri Nokogiri!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was running into the same exact problem.

I had to install

```
gem pristine nokogiri
```

I then ran

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

And then got

```
Restored nokogiri-1.6.2.1
Building native extensions with: '--use-system-libraries'
This could take a while...
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
Restored nokogiri-1.6.3.1
```

This seemed to fix the problem for me, hope this helps!